# Return stored procedure value

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, count

I am try to get the count of rows that have the searched ID.
I am using this to check duplicates.

I am unsure how to return the count as a variable so I can compare it.
I have the check `If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then` but it is always -1.
I have tried making a `Int row as Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and always -1.

So my question is... after I do the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` how do I grab the dataset value of the count amount and assign it to a value like `Dim count as Integer = ....`

Stored Procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UserCheck
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ID bigint
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE ID= @ID;
END
GO
```

Vb.net

```
   Dim CS1 As String = ModuleGlobals.connectionString

    Using con As New SqlConnection(CS1)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.UserCheck", con)
        con.Open()
        'specify that it is a stored procedure and not a normal proc
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox3.Text)
        'Dim count As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then

            Dim CS As String = ModuleGlobals.connectionString
            Using con2 As New SqlConnection(CS)

                Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("dbo.Create", con2)
                con2.Open()

                ...add parameters here

                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con2.Close()
            End Using
        Else
            MsgBox("No user was created")
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**documentation for the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For **UPDATE**, **INSERT**, and **DELETE** statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.
>
> [...]
>
> **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Since your stored procedure only calls `SELECT`, it will always return -1.

If I'm not mistaken you have to use the [**`ExecuteScalar()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```vb
Dim count As Integer = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

Comment: I tried ExecuteScalar before but had errors; however, your format did work. Wasn't aware that is why people use the Scalar method. appreciate explanation you provided.

Comment: @narue1992 : Neither were I, since I have never really done any database programming :). -- Glad I could help though! Good luck!